# robovm plugin won't work

Tags: eclipse, robovm

I'm trying to use robovm on Eclipse. I have installed the robovm plugin.

But when I create a RoboVM eclipse project, Eclipse gives me an exception:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.robovm.eclipse.ui was unable to load class org.robovm.eclipse.internal.NewCocoaTouchProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.robovm.eclipse.ui (244).
```

I get a similar message when I try to go to "Settings" > "RoboVM":

```
Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.robovm.eclipse.ui (244).
```

Can anyone can help me?

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
```

Comment: Since I can't comment, i'll ask here, are you using the latest version of RoboVM (0.0.7)?

Comment: Yes, im using the latest Version. But i've found and solved the Problem today.
I had installed Java 6 AND 7. eclipse had use Java 6. For other peoples there have the same Problem:
Go to the Settings App > Java and go to the Java-Tab. Here are all installed Java versions listed. Change the priority for the version otherwise deinstall or disable older Versions. I hope you understand that, my english is not really good.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Can you please post that as an answer? It looks like it would be helpful to future readers :)

Comment: Had, but was deleted with unknown reasons!

Comment: @AdrianPreuss how did you install RoboVM on eclipse. I am unable to install please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A moderator has delete my answer - Confusing why (reason: "your post was converted to a comment")!

For future readers,
**Here is the right answer:**

> But i've found and solved the Problem today. I had installed Java 6 AND 7. eclipse had use Java 6.
>
> For other peoples there have the same Problem: Go to the Settings App > Java and go to the Java-Tab. Here are all installed Java versions listed. Change the priority for the version otherwise deinstall or disable older Versions.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by RoboVM.

Show following resources:

**Issue #246** on https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/246

**Commit #1702b68** from https://github.com/robovm/robovm/commit/1702b68ffd362788fab74a8d9cbf2bd6411bcf5f

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Add more content to the post.

Comment: @Raghunandan it is not a link only answer. The answer is "It was fixed in a recent build" and the link is to the issue on the bug tracker. The actual content of the answer is here.

Comment: Could be. at the first look of it looked like a link only answer. Any way I have not flagged it.  came up in the review queue