# RoboVM plugin 0.0.11 not working with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, robovm

When I create a RoboVM Eclipse project, Eclipse gives me an exception:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.robovm.eclipse.ui was unable to load class org.robovm.eclipse.internal.NewCocoaTouchProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.robovm.eclipse.ui
```

Likewise, I get this message when I try to go to "Settings" > "RoboVM":

```
Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.robovm.eclipse.ui.
```

I have updated to Java 1.7.
I am using Eclipse version 3.7.2 but I faced the same issue when I tried it with Kepler Service Release 2.

This issue is similar to [robovm plugin wont work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024474/robovm-plugin-wont-work) but the responses there didin't solve my issue, as I am already using the latest roboVM and JDK.

Comment: Did you see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024474/robovm-plugin-wont-work#comment33550534_21024474) on [robovm plugin wont work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024474/robovm-plugin-wont-work)?

Answer (score 2):

What OS are you running Eclipse on?  Guessing OSX Mavericks?

I *think* I had something similar and this resolved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21148562/19506. The problem I had was that I had installed Java 7 (as it sounds like you have) and it showed up in Eclipse as available. BUT, Eclipse itself wasn't running Java 7, it was using Java 6. And the plugin will only run in Java 7. I'm using Kepler SR2 fwiw.

I.e. You first install Java 7 (sounds like you did that), but *then* you have to make sure Eclipse runs with it - not just has it available in the build environment.

One trick was finding `eclipse.ini` by doing a right-click on `/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse` (or whatever you called it) and choosing `Show Package Contents`. Then I added these two lines to the `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

immediately before this line:

```
-vmargs
```

Then I closed and restarted Eclipse. At this point, the plug-in was able to run.

*Hope this helps... It was a few weeks ago and I remember doing this was the biggest stumbling block I had with getting RoboVM running. I just don't remember exactly what the error was!*

Comment: In addition to editing `eclipse.ini`, you can change the Eclipse Java compiler from a project's preferences window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540548/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-use-a-different-compiler-version-for-java

Comment: I have already tried by changing from the preferences window. It shows java 1.7 being selected but that also didin't work

Comment: My experience was that changing the preferences only affects the project you're building - NOT the Eclipse that's running and its plugins. I tried that first with no effect before editing eclipse.ini.

Comment: I tried by editing the eclipse.ini and then restarted the eclipse.
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs

But it still didin't work

Comment: Same error I'm guessing?  Also, what OS are you running? I remember seeing different things for Mavericks vs earlier OSX.

Comment: I'm running Mavericks, but I'm on the same page as Kanika, that didn't work for me.

Comment: :(  This thread reinforces the idea that it's a Java 7 related problem: http://blog.robovm.org/2013/10/robovm-006-is-out.html. And another here: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/204. I'm running out of ideas. (Sure you've seen these already, but just in case).

Comment: The format of `eclipse.ini` is very picky. Make sure `-vm` and the actual path are on separate lines. Better yet, read https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini and make sure you're following the instructions precisely.

Comment: Also, @mm2001 is right; changing the preferences in Eclipse do NOT change the JVM that Eclipse and its plugins are running in. You must edit `eclipse.ini` or specify the JVM on the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have lower version of Java as RoboVM expects you to use jdk1.7.x. I had this problem in Mac as Mac used to release its own version. So I downloaded Oracle Java 1.7 and then opened eclipse. Under eclipse Preferences -> Java - Installed JREs, I added the newly installed jdk and made it default, finally removed the Java 1.6 from Installed JREs. Then uninstalled RoboVM. Restarted Eclipse. Re-installed RoboVM. That's it.

Comment: Sanjal, as mentioned in one on my comments below, I am running it on JDK 1.7.x. and changed the jre to newer version in eclipse and then uninstalled and reinstalled but it did not work.

Comment: Do you have any other versions of jdk in your machine? Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: I am using mac and it is running on OSX Mavericks. Yes I have JDK 1.6 also but currently the version is set to 1.7 both in the preferences and eclipse.ini file also.

Comment: What do you see when you execute "java -version" in terminal? Also, in eclipse preference, under Java --> Compiler, what is set?

Comment: java -version" in terminal - it shows 1.7
eclipse preference, under Java  - is set to 1.7

Comment: @KanikaMaheshwari I really have no other idea as I got mine working after the steps I mentioned. Let us know if you get yours fixed and how.

Comment: @KanikaMaheshwari Did you get it fixed?

Comment: No, it did not. Not sure if it has to do with the mavericks